# Microsoft SQL Import Wizard truncating import row on {LF}

Tags: sql-server, csv, delimiter, wizard

I exported a row to a csv file using this query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/examplefile.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'  
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
FROM examplefile 
WHERE item_num=42616;"
```

One of the data columns in the row contains a `{CR}`.  I have looked at the byte string and it looks correct.  When I try to import this csv file into SQL using `{CR}{LF}` as the row delimiter, `'|'` as the column delimiter, it seems to get confused by the `{CR}`.  Since the wizard offers a number of options for row delimiters including `{CR}{LF}`,`{CR}`,and `{LF}`, I'm surprised it doesn't accept the entire row.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try the hex of a `{LF}` which is `0x0a`  or `{CR}` which is `0x0D`

Comment: You could try using `ENCLOSED BY` to put your fields in quotes (or a character of your choice) to help the Import Wizard distinguish between text content and row delimiters.

Comment: Yes, using ENCLOSED BY to put double quotes around all the fields solves import wizard's confusion with any embedded '\n's in the field.  MySQL ( 5.5.52-0 ubuntu0.14.04.1) even escapes any embedded double quotes ' " ', but the SQL import Wizard (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 13.0.16106.4) doesn't seem to recognize the escaped double quotes and remains confused.

Comment: It's odd that your double quotes are escaped by `'"'` since you specified `ESCAPE BY '\\'` which could be expected to escape like `\"`. I'd go for a different enclosing char like `~` or `^`.